# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported lang:

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lang

What is causing these errors?

- **Chrome error**

  > Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
  >   unsupported lang:
- **Firefox error**

  > Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
  >   unsupported lang:

It's something to do with my lang selector.

Currently I use:

```
var globalLangVar = ''; // determined by another function
$('.translation:lang('+globalLangVar+')')
```

There are other similar questions, this one is specific to **"unsupported lang:"**

Comment: you use a variable inside a string! you should use backtick, $(`.translation:lang(globalLangVar)`)

Comment: @Monala92 Thank-you for the tip! I will have to read more about template literals.

Answer (score 1):

This was being thrown because the language code was not known.

In my case it was blank as I had a function searching for a blank string from a variable that hadn't yet been determined by another function.

So check that all of your language codes are correct if you see this error.

- [List of ISO 639-1 codes @
  Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)
- [Another list of codes kept by
  W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)

My solution was to set 'en' as default for globalLangVar